# How can I get the tkinter entry from a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I wants to make a program with multiple tkinter Entry widgets.
I use a for loop to make multiple Entry widgets.
But how can I get the value from it?

My test code:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
variables = []
entries = []
for i in range(10):
    va = StringVar()
    en = Entry(root, textvariable=va)
    en.grid(row=i+1, column=0)
    variables.append(va)
    entries.append(en)

def hallo():
    print(en.get())
button=Button(root,text="krijg",command=hallo).grid(row=12,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use `StringVar`s, you need to use `get()` on those. However, there seems to be no need for you to use `StringVar`s, so you can just remove those and use `get()` on the entry widgets like so:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
entries = []

for i in range(10):
    en = Entry(root)
    en.grid(row=i+1, column=0)
    entries.append(en)

def hallo():
    for entry in entries:
        print(entry.get())

button=Button(root,text="krijg",command=hallo).grid(row=12,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```